# Create table in SQLite with generic class 'Quantity' as a picker - ERROR not a valid type for SQLite DB

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, picker

Morning All,

xamarin forms - populate picker in MVVM from SQLite DB issue

So...Ive used the following post

```
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/populate-picker-using-mvvm/
```

to help me include a populated picker using MVVM in my project, using a picker to allowing the user to select a 'Quantity' to order for each product (which all works fine as its populated from code, but now refactoring to load from SQLite..please see current code below)..

```
//ProductModel

     public class ProductModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private int _ProductId;
        private string _BrandName;
        public ObservableCollection<Quantity> _ListQuantites;
        private Quantity _selectedQuantity;
//ETC have removed the other properties for sake of this Q


        //Constructor
        public ProductModel()
        {
            //Subscription
            this.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ProductId
        {
            get { return _ProductId; }
            set
            {
                if (_ProductId == value) return;
                _ProductId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

  
        public ObservableCollection<Quantity> ListQuantites
        {
            get
            {
                return _ListQuantites;
            }
            set
            {
                _ListQuantites = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Quantity SelectedQuantity
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedQuantity;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    _selectedQuantity = _selectedQuantity;
                }
                else
                {
                    _selectedQuantity = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

   
        //OnPropertyChanged
        private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SelectedQuantity))
            {
                //test quantity amount
            }
        }

        // [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


Up Until now I was populating the ProductModel with its picker, from the constructor of the ProductViewModel page with:

 

         WineList = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
                    WineList.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 1, BrandName = "Mc guigans", Grape = "Red", ListQuantites = List_Quantites, Image = "W.png", Description = "Fruity Flav", Size="700ml", Price = 10.00M, SubTotalForItem = 0.00M, Genre = "Wine" });
    //etc...and so on

//then
 List_Quantites = PickerService.GetQuantitiesForProductPage();

//Picker service
     public static ObservableCollection<QuantityModel> GetQuantitiesForProductPage()
        {
            var quantities = new ObservableCollection<QuantityModel>()
            {
                new QuantityModel() {Key=1, Value="0"},
                new QuantityModel() {Key=2, Value="1"},
                new QuantityModel() {Key=3, Value="2"},
                new QuantityModel() {Key=4, Value="3"}
//etc
            };
            return quantities;
        }


//XAML

    <Picker Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Title="     " VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="productPicker" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListQuantites}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" SelectedIndexChanged="QuantityChanged" SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedQuantity}"/>
```

So...yeah as I said all works fine and dandy...But now I would like to load the ProductModel list from a table in SQLite....I have already used SQLite basic CRUD operations to create, load, view, update, edit...etc for orders made...so this is also working...the problem I seem to be having is creating the table, it is failing when I try to create an entry in the table with 'Quantity'....obviously...so I have changed the code...change 'Quantity' to object, then the plan being to populate this on the VM...but this also didnt work...

found another post relating to this:

```
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2546/create-table-in-xamarin-throws-exception-because-of-generic-list
```

So 'Quantity' class is not a valid type for SQLite DB value...but turns out neither is object...has anyone idea for a work around for this...or some advice on how to refactor to resolve this?

any help or point in the right direction is appreciated thank Y

Comment: SQLite, like most databases only understands primitive types.  Quantity is not a primitive.  It would be much simpler to just use an int, but if that is not an option you need to use SQLite.Net Extensions to define a FK relation to a Quantity table.

Comment: Hi Jason, yes but I think that only solves half the prob...if you note the example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/populate-picker-using-mvvm/ in the MainPageViewModel  class... to use a picker...3 properties are used...ListCites, that returns a list of cities, SelectedCity that return the selected citiy and CityText that represents the value of the city....In the same way when I am creating  ProductModel I need to add the SelectedQuantity (which is what youre talking about with FK to the Quantity table) but how do I add the Quantity class to a property in my ProductModel DB Table?

Comment: you have to create a Quantity table it you want to model it as a distinct type.  Or you can just use an int and greatly simplify things for yourself

Comment: Hi Jason, yes OK youre right..probably best to keep it simple...but if I go with int so 'Quantity SelectedQuantity' becomes 'int SelectedQuantity' How do I store the 'ObservableCollection<Quantity> ListQuantites' (which populates the picker on drop down) in the ProductModel SQLite DB table...I cant add List<int> as 'list' is not primitive?

Comment: is there any reason that needs to be stored in the DB, and cannot be generated in the Model/VM?

Comment: generated in the model? I was under the assumption the model properties have to match those of the DB table? (Previously I was thinking along the lines of an object property and then converting that to a list of int, and populating in the VM...but this way the object originally existed in the DB table...wat you suggest is adding another property to the ProductModel (from the code) that doesnt exist in the db table?) am I missing something? is this possible?

Comment: I feel like you're making this much more complex than it needs to be.  Just hardcode the values for the Picker in the XAML or codebehind - they don't need to be databound to the VM.

Comment: yeah you're right...I was trying to keep everything in the code behind but alas....thanks again for taking the time to help with this Jason, if you want to write an answer ill mark it. Ta